# Expected unqualified-id before 'not' token C++

Tags: c++

I don't know why this error is there, I can't figure out why it is showing up. Someone please help!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int not(int x){
    cout << Enter your number;
    cin >> x;
    if(x==1){
    return 1;
    }
    else{
    return x * (x-1);
    }
}

int main(5)
{
    cout << not();
}
```

Edit: The error is on line 5 if it helps.

Comment: `int main(5)`? Typo?

Comment: `cout << not();`  `not` should be called with argument.

Comment: @Ari0nhh, It's worse than that. See Nicky's answer.

Comment: @Ari0nhh Or the other way round, there is no point passing `int x` as parameter, given how x is used. And I start to think the `5` in the typo is meant to be in the function call.

Comment: @NickyC Good point)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`not` is an *alternative token*. It is used as an alternative spelling of operator `!`. It cannot be used as a function name.

Although an alternative token is technically not a *reserved keyword*, both kinds cannot be used as names.

See:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative

Comment: Actually `not` is not a keyword.  It is a so-called multigraph which is replaced by `!` by the preprocessor.  A consequence is that you can denote references by `int bitand ref = val;`, etc.

Comment: @HenriMenke Let me think of a way to edit the answer for correctness without diving too deep into the technicality.

Answer (score 1):

The token 'not' is one of the keywords that c++ preserve. You can not use 'not' to name a function.

What's more is that there are some other errors in your code, such as the function call misses a parameter. The following code would be what you want I suppose.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int not_func(int x){
    cout << "Enter your number";
    cin >> x;
    if(x==1){
    return 1;
    }
    else{
    return x * (x-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << not_func(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The token 'not' is one of the keywords that c++ preserve. You can not use 'not' to name a function.**
also ....i think there is no need to pass anything from main since you are entering it though function.(unusable code)

```
    #include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int nott(int x){
    cout <<"Enter your number";
    cin >> x;
    if(x==1){
    return 1;
    }
    else{
    return x * (x-1);
    }
}
int main(){//no need to pass any thing
    int x;    
    x=nott(5);
    cout<<x;
}
```